# Issues with dns_get_record

Tags: php, dns

I am trying to configure a script to find out if a clients A Record has been setup yet. The problem is, I have already parked the A Record on my cPanel account.

Therefore, when I use

```
$ip = dns_get_record(URL, DNS_A);

if ($ip[0]['ip'] == IPADDRESS) {
    echo '<div style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">DNS Correct</div>'; } else { 
    echo '<div style="color:red; font-weight:bold">DNS Config Error</div>'; }
```

or via gethostbyaddr() it will show that the A record is correctly setup and pointing to my server.. but its not. It is only pointing to my server because i have parked the A record in the DNS.

The script muse somehow first checks with the current servers DNS records before proceeding to the global registry?

Is there a way to check the remote DNS registry first?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to first find the authoritative name server for the domain if not already known, then do a dig command on it and check the results for an answer.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example code I can use or recommend where I can start looking?

Comment: It's very messy code, but my site at http://dns360.jwebnet.net/ does a dig using php and cgi and returns the full results. You may want to take a look.